# How can I get GDB to stop tracing a detached process?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I'm debugging a C++ application which creates trees of forks. Using GDB defaults, the child processes will be detached on the fork and as a result I see only one inferior shown afterwards.

I tried to attach to one of the child processes and despite it not being listed as an inferior for the other GDB process, in the new GDB session I get an error that the process is already being traced (by the first GDB session).

Is this expected behavior? What steps can I take to debug the forked process in a separate GDB session? What steps can I take to debug the problem further?

Comment: did you set `follow-fork-mode` or `detach-on-fork` ?

Comment: I've tried all combinations of both